# How to calculate how many $\sigma$ away is the experimental data from the theory?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, statistics

I am confused with the all these how many $\sigma$s arguments. Let's say we have a measurement and we want to compare it with a theoretical value.

Let's say the measurement is: M=15.1 $\pm$ 1

and the theoretical value is: M=17.4 $\pm$ 2.5

How many sigmas should be the difference ? I thought the sigma is 1 and the difference is
$(17.4-15.1)/1=2.3 \sigma$ but according the results of [this paper](https://www.science.org/doi/epdf/10.1126/science.abk1781) on page 6, last paragraph, it is not calculated this way.

Comment: High energy physics measurements rarely have Gaussian error distribution and theory and experimental data are not independent (the theory uses the same assumptions as the data analysis), so the trivial analysis a no-no for starters. Also see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186463/distribution-of-difference-between-two-normal-distributions for the case of independent Gaussian distributions.

Answer (score 1):

Almost: you just need to do proper error propagation, i.e. add both the uncertainties in quadrature:

$\frac{17.4-15.1}{\sqrt{1^2+2.5^2}}=1$

Or, using the numbers from your paper:

$\frac{80433.5-80357}{\sqrt{9.4^2+6^2}}=7$

which is in agreement with the 7 sigma that the authors write.

Note that decimals of sigma don't really matter for anything, and anyway this calculation implies a number of assumptions, e.g that the errors are independent and Gaussian. But it's a good cross check of course and quickly gives you an idea how excited you should get about your result.

Answer (score 0):

We have two results, the theoretical $\bar y_{theo}$ and the measurement $\bar y_{meas}$. Each of these average values is associated with its uncertainty, $Sd[\bar y_{theo}]$, and $Sd[\bar y_{meas}]$. Therefore, the question is: "How confident are we about the **difference** of the two results $\Delta = \bar y_{meas} - \bar y_{theo}$?"

The common hypothesis test would be to check if the difference is zero. Thus, we setup the hypothesis pair
$$H_0: \Delta = 0$$
$$H_a: \Delta \ne 0$$
Now, if certain assumptions are valid (such as that the difference is normally distributed), we can perform a $z$-test (or a $t$-test) to statistically answer the question. The test statistics is
$$ Z = \frac{\Delta - 0}{Sd[\Delta]} 
=  \frac{\Delta}{Sd[\bar y_{meas} - \bar y_{theo}]}
=  \frac{\Delta}{\sqrt{Sd[\bar y_{meas}]^2 + Sd[\bar y_{theo}]^2} }
$$
which yields in your case $Z=(17.4-15.1)/\sqrt{1^2 + 2.5^2} \approx 0.854$.